# Rails, get Class from Class name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an issue here where I'm trying to call a class method on an object that is not known... err, I'm not sure how to phrase this I'm getting the :resource from the URL, but I want to run find on it for a differnt param as well.

How can I do something like:

```
params[:resource].classify.find(params[:id])
```

I mean this won't work because the `params[:resource].classify` would be a string. But how can I run a method on it as if it was a `Class` and not a string?

The following used to work fine but the gem `friendly_id` has made all my calls to a record to return it's friendly_id and not its actual primary key... which totally sucks.

It was doing something like this, which worked just fine:

```
@vote = Vote.new({
  :vote => params[:direction] == 'up' ? true : false,
  :voteable_type => params[:resource].classify,
  :voteable_id => params[:id])
})
```

But since adding `friendly_id` my paths now look something like:

```
/things/my-thing-name/vote/up
```

instead of the old way:

```
/things/328/vote/up
```

So now the `params[:id]` is no longer the foreign key.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question, it seems like 2.

For part 1, you can `constantize`. `params[:resource].classify.constantize` should return the classname that you can then invoke a method on. Just to be safe, you might want to `tableize` before `constantize`ing, just to make sure things like "-" are going to be "_". I only mention this because of how you have your `friendly_id` set up.

As for part 2, I don't know the `friendly_id` gem, but based off of the description of how it works in [the guide](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/file.Guide.html), your find should still work just fine unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

For the first thing "params[:resource].classify" you need to do

```
params[:resource].constantize
```

For the second it looks like you should do something like:

```
@thing = Thing.find_by_friendly_id(params[:friendly_id])
```

Comment: If his `params[:resource]` is returning "things" he should still `classify` or else `constantize` has a good chance of flipping out with a "wrong constant name" error.